# scala Iterator#foreach performance issue

Tags: scala, scala-collections

To iterate an Iterator, we can call its `foreach` or use while loop. The implementation of `foreach` is:

```
def foreach[U](f: A =>  U) { while (hasNext) f(next()) }
```

So I think `foreach` should as fast as `while(iterator.hasNext)`, but after doing some test, the results surprise me very much.

my test code:

```
def getSize2[T](i: Iterator[T]) = {
  var count = 0
  val f = (a: T) => count += 1
  while(i.hasNext) {
    f(i.next)
  }
  count
}

def getSize3[T](i: Iterator[T]) = {
  var count = 0
  val f = (a: T) => count += 1
  i.foreach(f)
  count
}
```

It is very weird that `getSize2` is 3 times faster than `getSize3`!

Anyone know what happened there?

Edit:
paste my test program

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {
  val data = 0 to 100000000

  val start2 = System.nanoTime
  (0 to 100).foreach(_ => getSize2(data.iterator))
  println("get size, while loop, using function: " + (System.nanoTime - start2)/1000000)

  val start3 = System.nanoTime
  (0 to 100).foreach(_ => getSize3(data.iterator))
  println("get size, foreach: " + (System.nanoTime - start3)/1000000)

}
```

My OS: ubuntu 12.04,  scala version: 2.10.3

Comment: Can you write how you measured the execution speed? I mean actual code and command line you executed. additionally scala version and which OS you are running.

Comment: Look at the bytecode and you'll see the foreach is doing more invocations.

Comment: That's interesting because I'm seeing opposite results.  while (iter.hasNext) { count += 1; iter.next() } takes some 6 times longer.

Comment: An update:  Checking this result with Scala 2.11.12, I get that the given test code runs the while loop about 30% faster using an underlying mutable.ArrayBuffer with a million integers.  However, if one changes the "Iterable[T]" parameter to "Iterable[T]" (adding "val i = input.iterator" to the while loop) then the while loop runs about the same speed, but the "foreach" runs over ten times faster here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The while loop is faster because a function call is not free and cannot always be removed by the JIT compiler.  In particular, `var count` is wrapped in an anonymous object so it can get access to it from within the function object, and to really speed things up the JIT compiler needs to unwrap everything and then finally realize that it never needed the anonymous object at all.

Adding the extra layer of a function call out to the library foreach really complicates the JIT compiler's analysis (three layers of indirection instead of two, etc.).

Comment: I also wrap `var count` in an anonymous function object in the while loop version. Do you mean JIT is more likely to remove function call in the while loop version rather than the foreach version?

Comment: @cloud - Yes, that's what I mean.  There's less work to do, which often makes a difference.  (Edited the answer to be clearer about that.)